# Display single element page on click of list element wxpython

Tags: python, wxpython

I have been working on my first wxpython app and this app has a search functionality. The app has to search for elements from database, list them and display details of one single element, when the element is clicked from the list.

I found there is `ListView` or `ObjectListView` to be used for this. But what should be used so that on click of a single element in that list, I should display the panel which displays the dynamic data for that particular element?

Answer (score 0):

I found out that wx has a EVT_LIST_ITEM_ACTIVATED event that is triggered when a list item is double clicked. I used this to capture the selected item and display the data accordingly.